# jquery autocomplete ui in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I tried using jquery autocomplete ui with my codeigniter web app, but I have some issues with response and selector function.
I have 2 input fields one with id as 'source-id' which is hidden and another one with id 'source' which is visible to the user.

```
<input type="hidden" name="source-id" id="source-id">
<input type="text" id="source" name="source" placeholder="Source">
```

and i have the following jquery code

```
jQuery(function($){
        jQuery("#source").autocomplete({'autoFill':true, 'focus':function(event,ui) {
            $('#source-id').val(ui.item.value);
            $('#source').val(ui.item.label);
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#source').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#destination').focus();
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
                if(!ui.item) {
                    $('#source').val("");
                    return false;
                }
            },
            source: function(request, response){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/bus/autocomplete');?>",
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

i have the following response from codeigniter controller

```
{ value:"1", label:"abcd"}
```

what I need is to fill the visible input with the label 'abcd' and fill the hidden input with value '1'
but whenever i tried to run autocomplete, both the inputs get filled with value '1'

Comment: Follow this doc and see how the search.php is responding with data https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote , Try outputting similar response from your jquery controller as well (wrap it in array). This should definitely fix your problem

Comment: I think there is no issue with the controller since what I wanted from the controller is displayed in response,

Comment: Try wrapping the response inside an array like [{"id":"Passer domesticus","label":"House Sparrow","value":"House Sparrow"}]

Comment: If you go to the jquery ui website [remote-jsonp][https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp] and look at what json looks like, you will see that it is an [array of objects](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php?callback=jQuery112409820267792109847_1591823650184&term=re&_=1591823650187)